# Can I use a dynamic array as C++ template typename?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, dynamic-arrays

As for code below:

```
template<typename PatternType>
cl_int enqueueFillBuffer(
    const Buffer& buffer,
    PatternType pattern,
    ::size_t offset,
    ::size_t size,
    const VECTOR_CLASS<Event>* events = NULL,
    Event* event = NULL) const
{
    cl_event tmp;
    cl_int err = detail::errHandler(
        ::clEnqueueFillBuffer(
            object_, 
            buffer(),
            static_cast<void*>(&pattern),
            sizeof(PatternType), 
            offset, 
            size,
            (events != NULL) ? (cl_uint) events->size() : 0,
            (events != NULL && events->size() > 0) ? (cl_event*) &events->front() : NULL,
            (event != NULL) ? &tmp : NULL),
            __ENQUEUE_FILL_BUFFER_ERR);

    if (event != NULL && err == CL_SUCCESS)
        *event = tmp;

    return err;
}
```

The code can be compiled if the array length, **6**, is static designated.

```
queue.enqueueFillBuffer<float[6]>(buffer, nodes, 2345, 123456);
```

My question is how to make the length, 6, to be a variable and pass the compilation? Since dynamic array is supported in C99, sizeof(float[n]) can properly get the size (for the code **sizeof(PatternType)**). But I cannot make the code below pass the compilation:

```
int n = 6;
queue.enqueueFillBuffer<float[n]>(buffer, nodes, 2345, 123456);
```

Comment: `n` is not a compile time constant, therefore the compiler cannot deduce the static array type at compile time.

Comment: It would be nice to reduce your code snippet to the minimum which is needed to understand your question. For your example you can provide an empty function. Thats really enough!

Comment: Yes, the compiler cannot deduce the static array but why it cannot dispose it by the way of dynamic array.

Comment: I reserve the whole code snippet because it is a third-party library header file and I think it is a design defect.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such thing as a dynamic array in C++ (some compilers offer this as extensions).

Comment: How many possible value `n` can take ?

Comment: I know you just wanna make partial specialization for n value, right?

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `std::array`. More generally, assume that an STL-like container will be passed to your method. For instance,

```
std::array<float, 6> nodes;
nodes[0] = ...
```

or

```
std::vector<float> nodes;
nodes.resize(6);
nodes[0] = ...
```

Then the lines

```
static_cast<void*>(&pattern),
sizeof(PatternType),
```

may be replaced with

```
static_cast<void*>(pattern.data()),
sizeof(typename PatternType::value_type) * pattern.size(),
```

The compiler can then deduce the type, so calling the method then simply becomes

```
queue.enqueueFillBuffer(buffer, nodes, 2345, 123456);
```

No need for explicit template arguments.

Comment: Oh no. The code "static_cast<void*>(&pattern),
sizeof(PatternType)," cannot be modified. It is from OpenCL 1.2 C++ Wrapper header file. It is just the key of problem. I think it is a design defect. I don't know whether the Khronos Group member can see it.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm assuming [you're using this header file](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/api/1.2/cl.hpp). You can fork and modify it, otherwise I don't see a solution.

Comment: Mike, a dynamic array in that case is certainly not valid because the compiler could not deduce the size of the template argument. I saw your bug submission to Khronos, but if you read the OpenCL spec carefully you'll notice that the pattern type is supposed to be one of the builtin types: "The data pattern must be a scalar or vector integer or floating-point data type supported by OpenCL as described in sections 6.1.1 and 6.1.2.". While the result should be the same, it really isn't valid to pass in an array as you are trying to do.

Comment: @Lee is right, see [page 85 of this PDF](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.2.pdf). In short, it says you apparently *must* use cl_* types. But on the other hand, those types are just typedefs for the usual `float`, `double`, etc, so in theory you should be able to work with an `std::vector<cl_float4>` or `std::vector<cl_float4>`

Comment: The specification said "The maximum value of pattern_size is the size of the largest integer or floating-point vector data type supported by the OpenCL device". It means the pattern size is ulong16, 128 bytes, at most. std::vector cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no way to finish it.
As for enqueueFillBuffer implementation, please refer: https://www.khronos.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1347
the max size of pattern supported is ulong16, 128 bytes.